# Using and IF Statement with "OR" on the same line (for names)

Tags: python

```
#Intro and Naming
def Intro_Name():
    global Name
    print("Hello, welcome to AJ's silly, nonsensical, and pointless world of redundancies! What is your name?")
    Name = input()
    if Name == ("Greg" or "Moody" or "Greg Moody" or "Professor" or "Professor Moody" or "Gregory" or "greg"):
        print("We don't seem to be in a creative mood today, but fine, no problem, none whatsoever. I hate creative stories too...")
        print(Name + " will be your name for this story!")
    else:
        print("Cool! Your name for this story will be " + Name)

#print    
Intro_Name()
```

When I test this code for the Name input, the "OR" booleans within the IF statement don't seem to work.  Please help, and I apologize if this question has already been asked.

Comment: use `if Name in ["Greg", "Moody", "Greg Moody", "Professor"]`

Comment: Do `name in ["Greg", ...]`. When you do `"Greg" or "Moody"`, the expression evaluates to `"Greg"` because of short circuiting.